# Can I select the children of a pseudo class in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'd like to select all of the child td elements of the second child of a tbody element.  Here is the selection I am trying to achieve:

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>I want to select this td</td>
            <td>And this one</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

tbody:nth-child(2) > td 
{
    //insert rules    
}
```

However this is not working. Does CSS3 support selecting children of pseudoclasses?  If not, any advice on how to achieve the above selection would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for you input.

Comment: A `<td>` can't be a child of a `<tbody>`

Comment: Hey guys, added some html to the original post.  My question essentially boils down to can I select the children of a pseudoclass in css3 as shown above.  If so, then I know to look for the issue elsewhere.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr:nth-child(2)` does what you asked for:

```css
tr:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
```

```html
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>not me</td>
      <td>And not me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I want to select this td</td>
      <td>And this one</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`tbody:nth-child(2) > td` won't work because only `<tr>` elements can be children of `<tbody>` elements.

Comment: Right, I added the html I'm selecting from to the post.  The td's are direct children of a tr which is a direct child of the tbody.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. My understanding of your explanation of the problem is that a td cannot be a direct descendant of a tbody, which is true. I was trying to explain that, in my case, the td is not a direct descendant of the tbody, but of a tr, which in turn is a direct descendant of the tbody, which is correct syntax. This is why I don't think what you mentioned is causing the issue.  I think what's causing the issue is that you can't select the children of a pseudoclass, but I can't find any confirmation or refutation of this.

Comment: But in your example you're using the pseudo-class selector on the tbody and then the child selector `>` and then a td which won't work. You could try tr instead of td.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  I misunderstood how nth-child() was making a selection.  I was selecting tds decendant of tbodys that are second children, which is incorrect.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Allen More: The long and short of it is that you don't select a child/sibling of a pseudo-class - you select a child/sibling of an element that *has* (or doesn't) a pseudo-class, in much the same way you select elements that *have* (or don't) IDs, classes or other attributes. Say you were selecting tr elements in the tbody second child instead, that would be tbody:nth-child(2) > tr. That's basically the same as tbody > tr except you're limiting it to the tbody that's the second child of its parent table.

Answer (score 0):

to select all second td try it:

```
td:nth-child(2)
{
  //
}
```

but if you wan't to select all td in the second child you can try :

```
tr:nth-child(2)
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can mix pseudo-selectors and the child selector (did you notice your typo on `child`?):

```
.a-class:nth-child(2n) > .child-class
```